# Find Items in Listbox from a collection and select them

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Hi I am new to Linq and had a question. I have a Listbox on my page with a checkbox list with products. In my codebehind when i bind my telerik Grid I want to find all products for that Order and select them. What is the best way to go through the list and select items in the Listbox? Please show with some code example? Thanks for your help

```
int orderId = ((Order)e.Item.DataItem.OrderId);
RadListBox chkProductList = (RadListBox)editItem.FindControl("chkProductList");

List<Product> orderProductList = orderBL.FindProductsinOrder(orderId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be exact, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
orderProductList.ForEach(x => chkProductList.Items.FindByValue(x.ToString()).Selected = true);
```

After doing a little research on the `CheckedListBox`, I think this is what you need:

```
orderProductList.ForEach(x => 
    chkProductList.SetItemChecked(chkProductList.Items.IndexOf(x.ToString()), true));
```

**EDIT**

Using the `RadListBox` control for ASP.NET AJAX, you can select an item by value like this:

```
orderProductList.ForEach(x => 
    chkProductList.FindItemByValue(x.ToString()).Selected = true);
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your answer I am trying to do what you mentioned There isnt a FindByValue, there is a FindChildByValue here is what I have and I dont see a Select property with what I am doing?  orderProductList.ForEach(x => chkProductList.Items.FindChildByValue<Product>(x.ProductId.ToString()) .Select?!?

Comment: @Shokwave: Edited my answer. I think the second example should work.

Comment: James i tried the second approach but the RadListBox im using doesnt show a .SetItemChecked() property :( The closest thing i found was orderProductList.ForEach(x => chkProductList.SelectedItems.Add(chkProductList.Items ...but cant find IndexOf here? or    orderrcgList.ForEach(x => chkRailcarGroupList.Items[x].Selected ? but it cant be x because then im just looping through the orderProductList and there could be more products then whats in just that list for that particular order

Comment: Okay, just to make sure that I get all of the details correct - this is a windows app, right? And you're using a `RadListBox`?

Comment: @Shokwave: Okay, I think I've got you sorted out now. This is a web app and you're using RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX, right? The last example should be correct.

Comment: Hey James Think thats close it builds ok but when the event fires...I am getting an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on that line

Comment: Check to make sure that the item it's trying to select exists in the ListBox.

Comment: Thankx for your help James!!  to get the checkboxes checked I did orderProductList.ForEach(x => 
    chkProductList.FindItemByValue(x.ProductId.ToString()).Checked= true);